# Hibernate - HQL parameters passing

Tags: hibernate, hql

I try to implement that (MySQL) using hibernate to create a report containing amount of notes per trade for a given day. I think that's pretty clear and selfdescriptive:

```
select customer.trade, COUNT(*) from customer join note where customer.customer_id=note.customer_id and note.CREATION_TS like '${DATE}%' group by customer.trade;
```

So far I have this. "%" is a wildcard. :

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
                    "select new ReportEntry(c.trade, count(*)) from customer as c join note as n where c.id=n.customer.id and n.creationDate like ':creationDate%' group by c.trade;")
                    .setParameter("creationDate", DATE_FORMAT.format(reportDate));
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
unexpected token: ':creationDate%'
```

Encapsulating with {} doesn't work. What is a proper way of opening and closing property id?

Comment: You missed an equal sgin '=' or a like operator before ':creationDate%'

Comment: Terzlya, true but not essential. Edited original post to fix it.

Comment: FYI, if you don't know the name of the field you're querying on, and you do know the exact shape of the query (as in this case), then Crtieria are a much better option. Some day, someone will name your date field "x';--drop database;go"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the "%" in the parameter, not in the query string.

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
   "select new ReportEntry(c.trade, count(*)) "
   + "from customer as c join note as n "
   + "where c.id=n.customer.id "
   + "  and n.creationDate ':creationDate' group by c.trade;")
  .setParameter("creationDate", DATE_FORMAT.format(reportDate) + "%");
```

Comment: in HQL what is the meaning of this `=:` or what is it called?

Comment: No such operator afaik. Maybe a new question would help?

Comment: not really worth a question since its a simple thing in HQL, (started learning about it today) but anw its called named parameter

Comment: Named parameter is `:name`; there's no `=` in it. It is worth a question. In fact, there are many questions about it already.

Comment: just to explain it, I was just doing an HQL query so not creating the classes or anything(they are already created in the system, im doing queries only) and I saw this `=:client`, now I fully understand it `:client` this is named parameter as someone here told me. the `=` is there since there is a where clause. Example `where ord.id= : id` then in the code there will be `setParameter("id", "123wqe1");` so its like saying 
 where ord.id=123wqe1